# Error : Can only find distinct value of specified columns if .keep_all is FALSE

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, databricks, sparklyr

Have: purchase records. Used sparklyr::sdf_sql to read spark table into tbl_spark.

Too large to output to local R data.frame on driver node using DBI::dbGetQuery
(10^8 rows and 30+ cols)

| Person_id | Trip_date | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-01-2021 | Apples | $1.50 |
| 1 | 30-01-2021 | Bananas | $0.89 |
| 1 | 27-01-2021 | Oranges | $1.00 |
| 1 | 27-01-2021 | Apples | $1.20 |
| 2 | 29-01-2021 | Grapes | $2.00 |
| 2 | 29-01-2021 | Apples | $1.20 |
| 2 | 28-01-2021 | Grapes | $2.50 |

Want: table of unique buyers, filtering by most recent trip.

| Person_id | Trip_date | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-01-2021 | Apples | $1.50 |
| 2 | 29-01-2021 | Grapes | $2.00 |

```
spark_version <- "3.1.0"
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
```

Five attempts

1.

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% distinct(Person_id, .keep_all=TRUE)
#Error : Can only find distinct value of specified columns if .keep_all is FALSE
```

2. 

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% 
      arrange(Person_id, desc(Trip_date)) %>%
      group_by(Person_id) %>% 
      slice(1)
# Error in slice_.tbl_spark(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : Slice is not supported in this version of sparklyr
```

3. 

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% 
       arrange(Person_id, desc(Trip_date)) %>%
       group_by(Person_id) %>% 
       slice_head()
#Error in slice_head(.) : could not find function "slice_head"
```

4. 

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% 
  arrange(Person_id, desc(Trip_date)) %>%
  group_by(Person_id) %>% 
  top_n(1)
#Databricks log: Selecting by Person_id
#Then later error when printing:
#org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'top_n_rank'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'
```

5. 

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% 
   arrange(Person_id, desc(Trip_date)) %>%
   group_by(Person_id) %>% 
   summarise_all(first) %>%
#Error in nth(x, 1L, order_by = order_by, default = default) :  object 'Product' not found
```

6.Index after grouping

```
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% 
      arrange(Person_id, desc(Trip_date)) %>%
      group_by(Person_id) %>% 
      mutate(RowN = row_number()) %>%
      filter(RowN == 1)
#Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid method count for object 44/java.lang.Class fields 0 selected 0
```

Can’t do summarise_all(min) because that jumbles the price column.

Does sparklyr support PostgreSQL and its DISTINCT ON syntax?

Further question: How much data can sparklyr collect – is size of driver node the only restriction

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.5    sparklyr_1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it gave the following result :

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
Price <- c("$1.50", "$0.89", "$1.00", "$1.20", "$2.00", "$1.20", "$2.50")
Product <- c("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges", "Apples", "Grapes", "Apples", "Grapes")
Trip_data <- c("30-01-2021", "30-01-2021", "27-01-2021", "27-01-2021", "29-01-2021", "29-01-202", "28-01-2021")  
Person_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(Price, Product, Trip_data, Person_id)
Fruit_purchases <- sdf_copy_to(sc, df, name = "Fruit_purchases", overwrite = TRUE)
Fruit_buyers <- Fruit_purchases %>% distinct(Person_id, .keep_all = TRUE)
print(sessionInfo())
Fruit_buyers

R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sparklyr_1.7.7 SparkR_3.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.3    uuid_1.1-0        tidyselect_1.1.2 
 [5] R6_2.5.1          rlang_1.0.2       fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_1.0.3      
 [9] blob_1.2.3        httr_1.4.3        dplyr_1.0.9       tools_4.1.3      
[13] parallel_4.1.3    config_0.3.1      utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.3.0        
[17] DBI_1.1.3         dbplyr_2.2.0      htmltools_0.5.2   ellipsis_0.3.2   
[21] yaml_2.3.5        rprojroot_2.0.3   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.29    
[25] tibble_3.1.7      Rserve_1.8-11     lifecycle_1.0.1   forge_0.2.0      
[29] crayon_1.5.1      tidyr_1.2.0       purrr_0.3.4       base64enc_0.1-3  
[33] htmlwidgets_1.5.4 vctrs_0.4.1       glue_1.6.2        compiler_4.1.3   
[37] pillar_1.7.0      r2d3_0.2.6        generics_0.1.2    jsonlite_1.8.0   
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3  
# Source:     spark<?> [?? x 4]
# Ordered by: `__row_num_95d8a414_5373_41a6_b78c_af4235f365b6`
  Price Product Trip_data  Person_id
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
1 $1.50 Apples  30-01-2021         1
2 $2.00 Grapes  29-01-2021         2
```